# Why UITableView is only accepting touches on first row?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I'm using a custom `UITableViewCell` with an `UIControl` and a few `UILabels` in my `UITableView` and everything works fine **only** if the `UITableView` takes up the whole screen. I'm using a xib file for this.

The problem is that I need to resize the `UITableView` to take only the bottom half of the screen, and like this only the first row accepts touches. Also if I try to scroll by pushing up from lower cells it won't do it, but will only scroll if I hold the first row.

It happens on both iPad and iPhone, but it's particularly bad on the iPhone. It seems that only on the bottom half of the screen the scrolling doesn't work.

I've already checked all views, and there is none above the `UITableView`, I've checked all sizes, I've googled and searched on Stackoverflow, but I couldn't find anything similar to my problem.

What else do I need to be checking? Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What is the size and position of the UITableView's superview in the xib file?  Sometimes when dragging a view around in Interface Builder it can be unexpectedly made a subview of another view. If that superview view doesn't have "Clip Subviews" checked the whole subview will be visible but only the part that falls within the bounds of the superview will be touchable.

Comment: I've just double checked the superview and it's OK, with Clip Subviews checked, but with no avail. Any other suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: This kind of thing is very hard to debug without seeing the .xib file...  If you make the table a little taller (so more of it appears above the bottom half), does the second row start accepting touches?  If you make it a little shorter, does the first row stop accepting touches?

Comment: Yes, if I make the table taller and drag it up the second and third rows accept touches. If I shorten it the table still accepts touches. I know it's hard to debug like that.

Comment: So the first row always accepts touches but the second row and beyond only accept touches when they are above the center of the screen?  I just want to make sure I understand you correctly.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your view hierarchy in Interface Builder?

Comment: Have you checked the contentSize and the bounds of the tableview? For UI related issues I would also suggest the great program Reveal. http://revealapp.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a custom Marquee `UILabel`, allocated and initialized via code and not via xib file, at the bottom of the screen and I was using the iPad frame instead of the iPhone one, so it was huge, being placed above the `UITableView`, consequently blocking it and preventing touch events.

As I was so focused on the xib file I totally forgot that I had setup this custom Marquee `UILabel` via code.

I thank Ethan Holshouser and Helium3 for all helpful comments above and the Reveal App suggested by Helium3 helped me greatly visualizing the views hierarchy to solve the problem.